# reveal a progressIndicator in Navigationbar

Tags: iphone, navigationbar

I want to display a revolving progress indicator in place of the title in NavigationBar when I click a button (refresh), and when refresh success, the indicator disappear and the title will be revealed again.

Any suggestions? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can code for adding UIActivityIndicatorView into UInavigatiobar like:-

```
 UIView *activityView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
 activityView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 UIActivityIndicatorView *act =[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init]; //create this globule so u can stop it while your progress finished
 act.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
 [activityView addSubview:act];
 self.navigationItem.titleView = activityView;
```

NOTE:-  `[act startAnimating];` and  `[act stopAnimating];` as par your Need

**Or you can add this into UInavigation BarbuttonItem**

```
    UIView *activityView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,30,30)];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *act =[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
    act.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    UIBarButtonItem *actItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityView] autorelease];
    [activityView addSubview:act];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = actItem;
```

NOTE:-  `[UIActivityIndicatorView startAnimating];` and  `[UIActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating];` as par your Need

Comment: thanks, it worked!But the position of the indicator is not correct, should I modify the frame of the activityView or the act?

Comment: yes i just put sample code you have to modify it's frame x or y as par your need..

Comment: with method u use first one or second one..?

Comment: I'm replacing the titleView, neither works, I've changed the frame of acitivityView and the act, but the actual position of indicator stays unchanged. I've googled and the position of titleView seems a common problem.